# how can I pass filelist of a build to mailnotifier in BuildBot?

Tags: buildbot

I use `Perforce` as CVS and plan to send mail when builds finish. In a buildstep, I can use `self.build.allFiles()` to get the filelist but I couldn't figure out a way to do so in the mailnotifier.

Answer (score 0):

[github issue](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/issues/3456)

You can use the `DataConnector` class to achieve that.

`changes = yield self.master.data.get("builds", buildid, "changes")
files = []
    for c in changes:
        files.extend(c['files'])`